Prioridade de requisição Postgre
Tem uma forma de priorizar quem faz requisições no Postgre? Tenho um usuário de sistema que fica em fila aguardando a execução de outros usuários.. Como faço pro Postgre responder primeiro o usuários de sistema e só assim aceitar comandos dos outros que possuem um nível de prioridade mais baixo?

Não repeita perguntas. Para continuar, se precisar comentar ou editar, faça na pergunta original: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/594602/3635
